# concatenating list of strings when they're split

Tags: r

I have developed a function that reformulates text into a useable expression within a linear model formula. However, when these formulas are too long, they split up. Therefore, I am trying to concatenate those strings that are split.

With some example data:

```
[[4]]$X7
[1] "lifespan ~ exposure + danger + body + brain"

[[4]]$X8
[1] "lifespan ~ danger + body + brain + nondream"

[[4]]$X9
[1] "lifespan ~ body + brain + nondream + dream"


[[8]]$X8
[1] "lifespan ~ danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + "
[2] "    gestation + predation"                                     

[[8]]$X9
[1] "lifespan ~ body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + "
[2] "    predation + exposure"                                         

lapply(formula_pred, lapply(x)if(length(x)>= 2){paste(x, collapse="")})
```

However, this would just paste all the strings in a list into one string per list.

For example, I get something like this:

```
[[1]]
[1] "lifespan ~ brainlifespan ~ nondreamlifespan ~ dreamlifespan ~ sleeplifespan ~ gestationlifespan ~ predationlifespan ~ exposurelifespan ~ dangerlifespan ~ body"
```

Expected output:

```
[[4]]$X7
[1] "lifespan ~ exposure + danger + body + brain"

[[4]]$X8
[1] "lifespan ~ danger + body + brain + nondream"

[[4]]$X9
[1] "lifespan ~ body + brain + nondream + dream"


[[8]]$X8
[1] "lifespan ~ danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation"                                     

[[8]]$X9
[1] "lifespan ~ body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure"
```

Reproducible code:

```
list(list(X1 = "lifespan ~ brain", X2 = "lifespan ~ nondream", 
    X3 = "lifespan ~ dream", X4 = "lifespan ~ sleep", X5 = "lifespan ~ gestation", 
    X6 = "lifespan ~ predation", X7 = "lifespan ~ exposure", 
    X8 = "lifespan ~ danger", X9 = "lifespan ~ body"), list(X1 = c("lifespan ~ brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation + ", 
"    exposure + danger"), X2 = c("lifespan ~ nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation + ", 
"    exposure + danger + body"), X3 = c("lifespan ~ dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + ", 
"    danger + body + brain"), X4 = c("lifespan ~ sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + danger + ", 
"    body + brain + nondream"), X5 = c("lifespan ~ gestation + predation + exposure + danger + body + ", 
"    brain + nondream + dream"), X6 = c("lifespan ~ predation + exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream + ", 
"    dream + sleep"), X7 = c("lifespan ~ exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + ", 
"    sleep + gestation"), X8 = c("lifespan ~ danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + ", 
"    gestation + predation"), X9 = c("lifespan ~ body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + ", 
"    predation + exposure")))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the OP's code, there is a syntax issue - i.e it shows `x` but there was no lambda function (`function(x)` or `\(x)` - in newer versions).  In addition, it is a nested list, so we may need two lambda functions

```
lapply(formula_pred, function(x) 
  lapply(x, function(y) paste(trimws(y), collapse = ' ')))
```

Or if we want to make use of `if/else` (not really needed as it gives the same result)

```
lapply(formula_pred, function(x) 
  lapply(x, function(y)
     if(length(y) >=2) paste(trimws(y), collapse = '') else y))
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
library(dplyr)
as.data.frame(dt) %>%
  mutate(across(matches("\\.\\d"), ~paste0(trimws(.), collapse = " ")))
                X1                  X2               X3               X4                   X5                   X6
1 lifespan ~ brain lifespan ~ nondream lifespan ~ dream lifespan ~ sleep lifespan ~ gestation lifespan ~ predation
2 lifespan ~ brain lifespan ~ nondream lifespan ~ dream lifespan ~ sleep lifespan ~ gestation lifespan ~ predation
                   X7                X8              X9
1 lifespan ~ exposure lifespan ~ danger lifespan ~ body
2 lifespan ~ exposure lifespan ~ danger lifespan ~ body
                                                                                     X1.1
1 lifespan ~ brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + danger
2 lifespan ~ brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + danger
                                                                                    X2.1
1 lifespan ~ nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + danger + body
2 lifespan ~ nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + danger + body
                                                                                 X3.1
1 lifespan ~ dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + danger + body + brain
2 lifespan ~ dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + danger + body + brain
                                                                                    X4.1
1 lifespan ~ sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream
2 lifespan ~ sleep + gestation + predation + exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream
                                                                                    X5.1
1 lifespan ~ gestation + predation + exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream + dream
2 lifespan ~ gestation + predation + exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream + dream
                                                                                X6.1
1 lifespan ~ predation + exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep
2 lifespan ~ predation + exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep
                                                                                X7.1
1 lifespan ~ exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation
2 lifespan ~ exposure + danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation
                                                                                 X8.1
1 lifespan ~ danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation
2 lifespan ~ danger + body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation
                                                                                   X9.1
1 lifespan ~ body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure
2 lifespan ~ body + brain + nondream + dream + sleep + gestation + predation + exposure
```